# What regex would detect if a string is part of a numbered list?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am really struggling to find a regular expression that will reliably check to see if a string is part of a numbered list (such as those you would find in a common word-processor)

Therefore, I would like it to return true if the **beginning** of the string is a **number** followed by a **fullstop** and a **space**.

For single or even double digit numbers I can of course do this easily without the need for regular expressions, but since the number could be any size, it will not work.

**Example 1**

```
"1. This is a string"
```

Should return **true** because the string begins with:  **"1. "**

**Example 2**

```
"3245. This is another string"
```

Should return **true** because the string begins with: **"3245. "**

**Example 3**

```
"This is a 24. string"
```

Should return **false**

Because there is no pattern matched at the beginning of the string... however...

**Example 4**

```
"3. This is 24. string"
```

Should still return **true**

I hope this is clear enough.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question. But before you do now, show us what have you tried?

Comment: See if the string starts with numbers and a period? Most regex tutorials will get you this far.

Comment: @RohitJain My apologies I assumed that the question in the title would be enough.

Comment: @DaveNewton Indeed that should be the case, but i've been reading tutorials all afternoon, If i'm quite honest, just cannot seem to get my head around regular expressions at all.  Hence my question.  I'm sorry if this is trivial for many people.

Comment: You should include at least one solution you've attempted, a case where it/they failed, and the expected/actual results. Show us what you know and can do so far.

Comment: Has your afternoon included [this tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)? Because it's actually pretty comprehensive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a pretty simple regex.  The following will find the start of the string, then a digit character repeated one or more time, then a period character, then the space character.

```
^\d+\.
```

### [REY](http://rey.gimenez.biz/s/umsicn)

In JavaScript you can do the following to test the string:

```
var startsWithNumber = /^\d+\. /m.test('34. this should return true.');
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ghjS5/3/)

Comment: Thank you, it works absolutely perfectly.  I really am sorry that this is so trivial for so many people but i've been struggling for hours.  I clearly seem to have some sort of mental blockage with regards to regular expressions!  Again, thank you for a great and concise answer.

Comment: @user2616246 There is no such thing as "mental blockage". You just need to learn the basics. You may start [here](http://regex.learncodethehardway.org/book/)

Comment: [be careful using the unescaped `.` character, it will produce incorrect results](http://jsfiddle.net/ghjS5/1/)

Comment: +1 You might want to use `\s` so the space is visible though.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do..

`/^\d+\.\s+/` or even `/^\d*\.\s*/`

Explanation of `+` and `*` operators

```
\d         Any digit
\s         Any whitespace character
*          Zero or more
+          One or more
```